# I'm from Pakistan and live in Turkey

Tags: schengen-visas, applications

I'm from Pakistan and live in Turkey.  I have one year residence permit of Turkey.  Can I apply for schengen visa from Turkey and what will be required documents for it

Comment: @Akhtar Jan Afridi For completeness, which particular Schengen country?

Answer (score 2):

In case of a Schengen visa, you **should** apply from your country of residence. For you that is Turkey.

Your documents should include your right to reside in Turkey (number of the residence permit, etc.) as well as your ties to your place of residence -- work contracts or university enrollment. Plus your financial situation in Turkey and your plans in the Schengen area.